# SQL Union not working when one table is empty

Tags: sql, union

Hi I am trying to read data from different tables with a SELECT statement and want to use UNION to get one dataset in the end. It is possible that one table does not (yet) contain data. In this case I can read the data from the first two successfully but once I use UNION to combine it with the data from the empty table the resulting dataset will be empty as well, even though it contained data from the first two datasets before.

My problem is, data is shifted between these tables irregularily so there is no way for me to know in which of the three tables I will find the data and in any case usually I have to combine results from more than one table to get the entire dataset I need (one contains data only 3 months back, the other two contain data for the last and the current year - depending on the period I need the data for it is possible that I have to look in all the three of them to collect all the data I need).

Do you know how I can check out all three tables and read data to collect the entire dataset I need?
I also tested if everything works in case all the three tables contain data, et voila it worked and I retrieved all the data I needed. So the statement itself should be OK, just not applicable to the special case where one table does not contain data.

I am using Python to connect to the database and retrieve the data via an sql statement.

So my sql statement currently looks like this:

```python
        sql_stmt = (
            "select " + sql_param+" from " + db_table +
            " where datum>=" + season_start_sql + " and datum<" + season_end_sql +
            " and statnr="+str(statnr) +
            " union" +
            " select " + sql_param+" from " + db_table +
            " where datum=" + season_end_sql + " and stdmin<=" + season_end_time_sql +
            " and statnr="+str(statnr) +
            " union" +
            " select " + sql_param + " from " + db_table + "_" + str(season_start.year) +
            " where datum>=" + season_start_sql + " and datum<" + season_end_sql +
            " and statnr=" + str(statnr) +
            " union" +
            " select " + sql_param + " from " + db_table + "_" + str(season_start.year) +
            " where datum=" + season_end_sql + " and stdmin<=" + season_end_time_sql +
            " and statnr=" + str(statnr) +
            " union" +
            " select " + sql_param + " from " + db_table + "_" + str(next_year) +
            " where datum>=" + season_start_sql + " and datum<" + season_end_sql + 
            " and statnr=" + str(statnr) +
            " union" +
            " select " + sql_param + " from " + db_table + "_" + str(next_year) +
            " where datum=" + season_end_sql + " and stdmin<=" + season_end_time_sql +
            " and statnr=" + str(statnr) +
            " order by datumsec")
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if one of a UNION's two tables is empty, you will still get the data from the other table.

Comment: I rather suspect your use of string concatenation for getting values into the query adds some rogue value and the whole query in fact errors out. Use parameterized queries. You may also need to revise your schema. It seems like you have a table for every year. Don't do that, have one for all years and denote the year in an extra column. And why the `UNION` at all? Is this for performance reasons? Because it could be expressed much simpler by using `OR` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Unforutnatley I can not change the schema of the tables.. I am not in charge of the database but just using the data in it. Also, if I understand it right and OR would not result in a dataset including data from all tables...? It is possible that I need to read data from each of them do collect the entire dataset I need.

Comment: OK, I overlooked that there are actually three tables involved. So you'd need to `UNION` the results from them. But per table you need only one query, if you use `OR` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: What is your DBMS? Maybe it has some possibilities to query table by pattern like in [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables).

Comment: @stickybit Ok thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: @astentx I am not quite sure - I am very new to databases sql and so on.. but I says it is a Sybase database - does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

This statement is simply untrue:

> once I use UNION to combine it with the data from the empty table the resulting dataset will be empty as well, even though it contained data from the first two datasets before.

If one of the components of a `UNION` is empty, then you will still get the results from the other tables.

Note:  If one of the tables does not *exist* -- which is quite different from being empty -- then the query returns an error, but not an empty result.

I will note that in general you should be using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, to avoid the overhead of removing duplicate values. And your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks and to unexpected syntax errors. I would question whether your application can be designed so you don't have to use dynamic SQL for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ... As you can see I am new to sql and might not find the underlying problem. All I know is that using the first three select statements only works and I retrieve data, adding the later three which each call upon a table that currently does not contain data for the requested "datum" makes me retrieving an empty dataset. However, all of these tables exist and also I catch the error that is returned in case one table does not exist.. In this case I create a new sql statement without the select statement for the missing table

Comment: @vroni - Try debugging your code to find the exact string that's actually being executed, or just add a print statement to get at it.  Then run that SQL code in a SQL Client *(such as SQL Server Management Studio, or MySQL Workbench, or whatever suits you the most)*.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for your comment, yes I will try to debug the code again... However testing the exact same code with the exacte same sql statement for a different period of which I know that all tables contain some of the data I need worked fine before... But I guess I must have missed something

Comment: @Vroni If it worked for one period, but didn't work for another period, you need to get the ***exact*** sql code that didn't work.  There's no point making assumptions.  Let the python write the SQL, extract it, and debug that SQL ***separately*** from the python (in a SQL client).  If you find that the SQL contained a mistake, you can ***then*** try to work out why the python generated SQL with that mistake in it...

Comment: @MatBailie Ok, yes I guess I will have to look into it again.